# Using bootstrap-table on a table with buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sorting, bootstrap-table

I have been trying to include a sorting function on my bootstrap table. The table contains buttons to dialogs and I want to sort the table on the button values. Here is the complete code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <h2 class="text-primary">Test Results</h2>
         <br/>
         <table class="table table-condensed" data-sort-name="pass_count" data-sort-order="desc" id="core_table">
            <thead>
               <tr class="info">
                  <th data-field="test_name" data-sortable="true"><b>Test Suite</b></th>
                  <th data-field="pass_count" data-sortable="true"><b>Pass</b></th>
                  <th data-field="fail_count" data-sortable="true"><b>Failure</b></th>
                  <th data-field="error_count" data-sortable="true"><b>Error</b></th>
                  <th data-field="time" data-sortable="true"><b>Time</b></th>
                  <th data-field="result" data-sortable="true"><b>R</b></th>
               </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>TestCopyrightFile__qa-old_TestResults_xml</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">0</button></td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">0</button></td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TestCopyrightFile__qa-old_TestResults_xml_Error">1</button></td>
              <td>0.801</td>
              <td bgcolor='#2EFEF7'></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>TestAOS_testAos_qa-old_TestResults_xml</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TestAOS_testAos_qa-old_TestResults_xml_Pass">2</button></td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TestAOS_testAos_qa-old_TestResults_xml_Fail">1</button></td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">0</button></td>
              <td>2.144</td>
              <td bgcolor='#FF0000'></td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
     <div class="modal fade" id="TestCopyrightFile__qa-old_TestResults_xml_Error" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="overflow-y: initial; max-height:85%;  margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom:50px;">
           <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                 <h2 class="text-primary">Error testcases from TestCopyrightFile: : qa-old: TestResults: xml</h2>
                 <br/>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="height: 250px; overflow-y: auto;">
                 <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                       <tr class="info">
                          <th><b>Test</b></th>
                          <th><b>Time</b></th>
                          <th><b>Result</b></th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                          <td>Error: testCopyrightFile can't convert nil into String</td>
                          <td>0.801</td>
                          <td bgcolor='#2EFEF7'></td>
                       </tr>
                    </tbody>
                 </table>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="TestAOS_testAos_qa-old_TestResults_xml_Pass" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="overflow-y: initial; max-height:85%;  margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom:50px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
              <h2 class="text-primary">Pass testcases from TestAOS: testAos: qa-old: TestResults: xml</h2>
              <br/>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body" style="height: 250px; overflow-y: auto;">
              <table class="table table-condensed">
                 <thead>
                    <tr class="info">
                       <th><b>Test</b></th>
                       <th><b>Time</b></th>
                       <th><b>Result</b></th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>Verifying correct response code is returned</td>
                       <td>1.742</td>
                       <td bgcolor='#00FF40'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>Verifying correct response is returned</td>
                       <td>0.007</td>
                       <td bgcolor='#00FF40'></td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
              </table>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="TestAOS_testAos_qa-old_TestResults_xml_Fail" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="overflow-y: initial; max-height:85%;  margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom:50px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
              <h2 class="text-primary">Fail testcases from TestAOS: testAos: qa-old: TestResults: xml</h2>
              <br/>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body" style="height: 250px; overflow-y: auto;">
              <table class="table table-condensed">
                 <thead>
                    <tr class="info">
                       <th><b>Test</b></th>
                       <th><b>Time</b></th>
                       <th><b>Result</b></th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>Failure: testAos Assertion failed for Verifying correct response code is returned. status like. 200 expected but was 401.</td>
                       <td>0.006</td>
                       <td bgcolor='#FF0000'></td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
              </table>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>

<script>
$('#core_table').bootstrapTable({

});
</script>
```

When the script section is commented out the page is formatted correctly but when I apply the bootstrap-table to have sorting I get the code for the buttons in the table rather than the buttons and the sorting works on the code and not the values of the buttons. How can I get the buttons to show and the sorting to act on their values?

Thanks in advance

A

Here is a fiddle I have been working with https://jsfiddle.net/x6htxss0/
When the javascript is not present and the bootstrap-table script is not implemented the table looks how I want it to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINAL? EDIT SOLUTION:

Setting the escape option to false when initiating the bootstrapTable will resolve this problem:

```
$('#core_table').bootstrapTable({escape: false});
```

I would recommend looking through the [bootstrapTable documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) (although that did not provide me with any solutions).

The quick and easy solution that I found was to replace the gt; and lt; that were being created from the plugin back to > and <. This will need to be done every time a sort is performed. You should be able to add an event listener to the onSort.bs.table event.

```
$('#core_table').find('td').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().split("&gt;").join(">").split("&lt;").join("<"));
});
```

EDIT

Here is the setTimeout hack. The sort.bs.table event fires before the plugin sorts and modifies the data. Possible solutions could be to modify the plugin to have an aftersort.bs.table event or better yet, render the data as html / not modify the data.

```
$('#core_table').on('sort.bs.table', function() {
      $('#core_table').find('td').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().split("&gt;").join(">").split("&lt;").join("<"));
});
```

EDIT: HACK SOLUTION

```
$('#core_table').off().bootstrapTable().on('post-body.bs.table',
    function() {
      $('#core_table').find('td').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().split("&gt;").join(">").split("&lt;").join("<"));
      });
});
```

Comment: I tried $('#core_table').on('sort.bs.table' function()) but either the sort was not available or the sort became available and the buttons reverted to their textual origins

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! It appears that the attaching the eventlistener to the sort.bs.table event does not work because it fires before the table is actually sorted. I was able to get it to work by adding setTimeout to the code above and just using 1ms. There is a brief flash of the html instead of the actual elements.  It should be possible to modify the plugin to have an aftersort event that would allow you to attach the code above but I am not savvy in that way. Perhaps it would wise to submit a request to the developer of the plugin but in the meantime you could use the setTimeout hack.

Comment: Hello again! I looked through the documentation for an event that might fire after sorting and found one. I updated my answer with it. "post-body.bs.table" instead of "sort.bs.table" works for me without any hacks (other than the split/join).

Comment: Ok Im confused here. Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x6htxss0/6/ When it first loads the textual version of the buttons appears. Its only on the sort that the buttons get rendered. Now when I try to code for the table to load with the buttons rendered the sorting option goes. Have you a fiddle with it working for both initial rendering and sorted rendering?

Comment: I cleaned up the JavaScript but here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yttLoq47/1/

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! Also, I just went through the plugin's code and found that if you initialize the bootstrapTable with option escape: false you won't need to use the hacks that I provided.
$('#core_table').bootstrapTable({escape: false});

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101808/discussion-between-cschaefer-and-amadain).